# How to determine (and fix) z-index of an anchor tag within a custom module?

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, custom-module

I have adapted Webtiki's [Responsive hexagon grid](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons) into a custom html module, however something is messing with the stacking of the anchor tag.

When I added the html to my joomla site, the link seems to be pushed down below the div's for the h1 and the paragraph which make the link un-clickable when you hover of the list item. The mouse indicates that the image remains a link before the two divs move in with the hover effect. If I change the z-index of the anchor tag, then the hover effect on the list item doesn't work, so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Here's a test server with the code in question [Test-Server](http://46.101.194.36/greentec-capital.com/index.php/portfolio/investment-criteria)

So, my question is why is the z-index for the anchor tag changed when it's incorporated into the site? (I realize that many things can affect the positioning of an element, especially with the multiple nested divs within the html generated by a CMS like joomla). Next, what can I do to diagnose or "fix" the z-axis positioning so that the link and the hover-effect both work? I've tried using the mozilla web developer tool bar to display stacking elements, but it doesn't show anything regarding the divs in question.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your site, else a JSFiddle?

Comment: I'll have to post a link to a live version a little bit later as it's all on my dev machine at the moment.

Comment: I just put the site up, the link is: http://46.101.194.36/greentec-capital.com/index.php/portfolio/investment-criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what you mean now. So there is no way to achieve this with your current HTML markup. Simply because if you change the `z-index` of the `<a>` element, the image will overlap the `<h1>` and `<p>`.

If you look at the [demo](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/wWGeEM), you can see that all the content is wrapped inside the `<a>`.

**Your current markup:**

```
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="/greentec-capital.com/images/gallery/bild4.jpg">
    </a>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Required markup:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="/greentec-capital.com/images/gallery/bild4.jpg">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: So, that's the way my original markup is for some reason the custom html module WYSIWYG editor won't preserve the a tags wrapping the image, h2, and p tags. Any idea why?

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: you, know I'm not sure but I think it's the TinyMCE...